# Derivation of an elasticity from a simple function $Y = \alpha\ln(x)$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

I have the following function $Y = \alpha\ln(x)$, $\alpha$ is a constant.   Question:

(a) What is the expression for the derivative of Y with respect to x?
(b) what is the elasticity of Y wrt. x?

Comment: This seems not related to statistics. It also looks like homework.

Answer (score 5):

a) The derivative of $\ln(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$ therefore $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x} = \frac{\alpha}{x}$

b) The elasticity of a function is calculated as $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}  \frac{x}{Y} = \frac{\alpha x}{Yx} = \frac{\alpha}{Y}$

I hope that is what you're looking for.